# How do I make a clip outside of method?

Tags: java

I created a method that either starts or stops music when called, but if I call it more than once, it starts a duplicate clip.  I can't find out how to make the audio clip variable outside of the variable to prevent this.

```
    public static void playSound(boolean play) throws Exception {
    File sound = new File("wave.wav");
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    if(play=true) {
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound);
        inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound);
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        clip.start();
    } else if (play=false) {
        clip.stop();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
So after a few hours of trying, I decided to just put the code to start music in the main method, make the clip variable static (so eclipse would let me use it in event) and then used clip.stop() on the event.  Just thought I'd share.

Comment: Maybe `if(play=true)` should read `if(play==true)`, or better still `if(play)`.  And the `else if` can just be `else`, since there's no other possibility if `play` is not true.

Comment: Also, if you stop a clip, you don’t to create a new to start playing again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the more complete answer, having the statement read like

```java
if(play)
{
    // Play code
}
else
{
    clip.stop();
}
```

Instead of

```java
if(play == true)
{
    // Play code
}
else if(play == false)
{
    clip.stop();
}
```

Is much better style.

**EDIT for additional information**

To answer the question's title,

> How do I make a clip outside of method?

I believe you are asking how to format a class-level variable. That requires the following:

- access modifier, need -- default(when you type nothing), public, protected, private
- final keyword, optional -- used to restrict the user
- static keyword, optional -- used for memory management
- data type, need -- specify the different sizes and values that can be stored in the variable
- name, need -- how the variable is called or referred to. Cannot be on the list of reserved keywords

With the same class that you use for this call: `Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();`, you can create an empty class-level variable with:

```java
private static Object objectName;
```

**Links**

- Access: https://www.javatpoint.com/access-modifiers
- Final: https://www.javatpoint.com/final-keyword
- Static: https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java
- Data Type: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-data-types
- Keywords/Reserved Words: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-keywords

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate issue is `if(play=true) {`, this is setting `play` to `true` and  therefore will reopen the clip and start playing it again every time.

You should be using `if(play==true) {` to determine if the value of `play` is `true`, but you could also use `if(play) {`

Take a look at [The if-then and if-then-else Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) for more details.

Essentially, `=` is for assignment `==` is for evaluation.  An if condition must equate to a boolean (`true`/`false`), so when using a boolean value you don't have to use `==`, you can just use the value itself.

Assuming `play` is `true`, both `if (play == true)` and `if (play)` will evaluate to `true`

Having said that, once you have the clip initialised and open, you don't need to re-open it when you want to start playing again, for example...

```
public class Track {
    private Clip clip;
    private File source;

    public Track(File source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public static void playSound(boolean play) throws Exception {
        File sound = new File("wave.wav");
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        if (play = true) {
            AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound);
            inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound);
            clip.open(inputStream);
            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            clip.start();
        } else if (play = false) {
            clip.stop();
        }
    }

    public File getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public Clip getClip() {
        return clip;
    }

    public void play() throws LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
        if (clip == null) {
            AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getSource());
            inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getSource());
        }
        if (!clip.isOpen()) {
            clip.open();
        }
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        clip.start();
    }
    
    public void stop() {
        if (clip == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (!clip.isActive()) {
            return;
        }
        clip.stop();
        clip.setFramePosition(0);
    }
}
```

In fact you could also easily add support for pausing by doing something like

```
public void pause() {
    if (clip == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (!clip.isActive()) {
        return;
    }
    clip.stop();
}
```

*(ps - I didn't add a close method which would also be pretty useful)*

Comment: @CatsyTart - To elaborate on this point -- **"... you could also use `if(play)`**@MadProgrammer** -- this is because the `boolean` variable `play` is already holding the value of either `true` or `false`. The compiler reads `if(play == true)` as `if(true == true)` or `if(false == true)`

Comment: @catsytart or it short terms, the if condition must evaluate to a boolean, true or false 

Comment: Don't forget to actually correct the `= true` business in the code.  And maybe do something about that otiose `else if` clause.